# Outlook connect to task events in Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, outlook

I found the following code in another post. Is it possible to capture Outlook task events in the same way?  There does not appear to be an equivalent of TMailItem for tasks - just Outlook2000._TaskItem (and if someone could kindly explain the difference between Outlook2000.MailItem and Outlook2000._MailItem it might give me a clue).  Thanks in advance.

```
uses
  ..., outlook2000;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    OutlookApplication: TOutlookApplication;
    procedure OnMailSend(Sender: TObject; var Cancel: WordBool);
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OutlookApplication := TOutlookApplication.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MailItem: _MailItem;
  Mail: TMailItem;
begin
  MailItem := OutlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem) as _MailItem;

  Mail := TMailItem.Create(nil);
  try
    Mail.ConnectTo(MailItem);
    Mail.OnSend := OnMailSend;

    MailItem.Recipients.Add('username@example.com');
    MailItem.Display(True);
  finally
    Mail.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnMailSend(Sender: TObject; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  ShowMessage((Sender as TMailItem).Body);
end;
```

Comment: You should do a little exploring on your own of the Outlook COM objects. http://www.berenddeboer.net/article/1292/1292.html

Comment: What task events do you need?

Comment: Dmitry, I need to detect when a task property has been changed - for example, the due date.  Thanks, Paul